# Gear S2 not displaying Keyboard

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I have a HTML-file with an "input" field. Upon selecting this field the Tizen Wearable Emulator opens the Keyboard to enter Text into the field. However the Gear S2 doesn't open the keyboard upon selecting the field.

Under Settings --> Input the Default Keyboard is set to "Samsung Keyboard". Is it possible to open this "Samsung Keyboard" when selecting my input field?

My HTML-Code is as follow

```
<input type="number" id="loginField" class="inputField">
```

With just some basic styling in CSS

```
.inputField {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: can you share your code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deployed exact your code to my Samsung Gear S2 & the keyboard showed up. It also worked on the emulator.

[image]

Would you please try to open a new basic project & just add the input field to make sure any other part of your current app/code is not stopping the keyboard to show up. Such as spacing/positioning issue or else.

Does the keyboard opens when you try to use the default 'Messages' app or any other application you loaded or developed?